# Add a prefix to package names by default?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ to work on a Scala project.  By default, if I add a new Scala class, the package declaration is automatically added to match the directory structure.  Also, if the package declaration does not follow this format, IntelliJ shows a warning.

However, the code base I am working on has a convention that all packages are be prefixed with the company name (so if the file is in `scala/some/folder` the package should read `company.some.folder`, but I'm getting `some.folder` instead).  Is there any way to set IntelliJ up to respect this instead of manually editing every file I create?

Comment: I am not sure if its possible. Look for settings if theres something, but my  guess is it does not. found little bit similar [JIRA issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109266#tab=Comments).

Comment: @prayagupd I tried that before posting a question, but I thought perhaps someone else would know.

Comment: Why don't you create `scala/company/some/folder` folder and place your files there?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Well, I didn't decide the standard, and I doubt anyone will be thrilled with my suggestion that we change the entire directory structure so that my IDE is more convenient to use.

Comment: It's not about IDE, it's about language conventions, package must correspond to the directory.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Clearly there is no such requirement, because it compiles and runs fine.  It is about the IDE in that my IDE, by default, picks namespaces that do not conform to the standard of the project I'm using.  If you want to tell me that it would be better for the namespaces and directory standards to agree, you'll get no argument from me, but the decision was made long before I had anything to do with the project.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA it's possible to [set the package prefix](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-content-roots.html#assign_package_prefix) for the source root specifically for such ill designed projects. In your case the package prefix would be `company`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder That does it!  I'd be happy to accept that if you posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA it's possible to [set the package prefix](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-content-roots.html#assign_package_prefix) for the source root specifically for such ill designed projects. In your case the package prefix would be `company`.

Comment: Also note that if you're using sbt, you can set it up from build.sbt, see https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2020/11/26/enhanced-package-prefixes/

Answer (score 1):

CrazyCoder's response works great, but if you want to set a lot of modules at once there's a faster way to do this than manually clicking on each and every one.

In the `.idea` folder at the root of your project, there is a `modules` folder.  In there are a bunch of `.iml` files for your modules with XML contents.  You can edit the `sourceFolder` nodes with the `packagePrefix` attribute to get the same effect and you can easily do this en masse by using the "find and replace in directory" option that appears if you right-click on the folder.